# Is there a way to select rows which is in a list of pairs in SQL?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table FOO with the following definition:

```
id   INTEGER,
type INTEGER,
data VARCHAR(32),
PRIMARY KEY(id, type)
```

I am given a list of pairs: (id, type) and I want to get all of the data which corresponds to those pairs (along with the id and type so I know what belongs to what). Can I do this in one query? (My specific dialect of SQL is SQLite)

Comment: Standard SQL has but one data structure: tables of rows. I presume SQLite doesn have data structures for 'pairs' or 'lists'. Please clarify your requirements in terms of tables, rows, columns, scalar parameters, etc. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to do this in SQLite is to do a bunch of `or` statements in a `where` clause. Or, you can do this:

```
select
    f1.*
from
    foo f1
    inner join (
        select 'id1' as id, 'type1' as type union all
        select 'id2', 'type2' union all
        select 'id3', 'type3'
    ) f2 on
        f1.id = f2.id
        and f1.type = f2.type
```

For edification, the `where` clause approach is:

```
select
    *
from
    foo
where
    (id = 'id1' and type = 'type1')
    or (id = 'id2' and type = 'type2')
    or (id = 'id3' and type = 'type3')
```

Comment: Wouldnt the where approach execute faster?

Comment: @chacham15 - Not necessarily. `or`s can really screw up the performance. The `inner join` would build a hash table and quickly join the tables rather than going through the list of predicates. That being said, try both and see which one is faster. I typically work in SQL Server, where an `or` in a where clause is a death knell.

Answer (score 0):

If you have many pairs, you could also have a second table holding the pairs.

```
select
    foo.*
from
    foo
    inner join pairs
        on foo.id = pairs.id and foo.type = pairs.type
```